# Fastest way to get the first non null value of a column with in a range of dates in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let' say i have the following SQL Table (with primary key:date),

```
date      foo
-------- ----
20181001 NULL
20181101   10
20181201 NULL
20190101    1
```

How can i get the first non-null value of the 'foo' column,

1. From date '20181001' to '20181101' ?
2. From '20181201' to '20190101' ?

What SQL server function should i use ? Please help with a function that is faster for the large tables with ~1Million records.

Comment: Can you show your expected result set?

Comment: @dnoeth, updated the question with sample input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to order the dates. Otherwise, you will not be able to find the first not null foo value. Because, the term first is relative. You need to have a order by clause to find the first not null value.

I have given sample code for your reference.

```
CREATE TABLE #test (datevalue DATE, foo INT);

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cix_test ON #test (datevalue);

INSERT INTO #test
VALUES ('20181001', NULL), ('20181101', 10), ('20181201', NULL), ('20190101', 1);

SELECT TOP 1 FIRST_VALUE(foo) OVER (
        ORDER BY datevalue
        )
FROM #test
WHERE datevalue BETWEEN '20181001'
        AND '20181101'
    AND foo IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: How can i make this work for multiple columns with datevalue between being different for each column ?

Comment: @deepak, as told by Tim Biegeleisen, I would suggest you to create one more question to avoid confusion for future visitors to this question

Comment: The query seems inappropriate, because it retrieves that first value multifold, as you are using an analytic function. So with thousand values in the date range you get a result of thousand rows all showing the first value. You can of course apply `DISTINCT` on the result, but this is a bit awkward in my opinion.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I prepared the query based on input data set user had given. You are right. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT date, foo, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE foo IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT date, foo
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you also want to restrict to a certain date range, then just add that to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT date, foo
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1 AND date BETWEEN '20181001' AND '20181101';
```

Comment: How can i get this working for multiple values ? Please refer to my latest edit.

Comment: I have reverted your question to what you asked originally.  It is rude and bad conduct on this site to make significant changes to your question after many users have already answered it.  If you have another problem, then you may ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The query is simply:

```
select top(1) foo
from mytable
where date between '20181001' and '20181101'
and foo is not null
order by date;
```

Then you'd have an index for quick access. I'd provide the following two:

```
create index idx1 on mytable (date, foo);
create index idx2 on mytable (foo, date);
```

The DBMS will choose one or the the other or none of them depending on selectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you you have a proper composite inde  index on

```
(foo, date)
```

and filter for

```
where foo is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 date FROM table WHERE date IS NULL ORDER BY date DESC
```

Select the null valued rows, order them desc by date, then select the top result. Should return the correct value.